# Unterschied zwischen „Ansicht“, „Anschauung“ und „Auffassung“

Tags: word-usage, difference, synonym

> **die Ansicht**: 
>       1. Meinung, Überzeugung 
>      2. Bild, Abbildung 
>    3. sichtbarer Teil, Seite, Front 
>    4. in »zur Ansicht«
>
> **die Auffassung**: 
>    1. Anschauung von etwas, Meinung, Ansicht  
>     2.  Auffassungsgabe
>
> **die Anschauung**: 
>      1. grundsätzliche Meinung, Betrachtungsweise 
>        2.a.   das Anschauen, Betrachten; Meditation 
>          2.b. Vorstellung, Eindruck

Quelle: Duden

Alle drei Definitionen sind einander sehr ähnlich. Gibt es Unterschiede in der Bedeutung der Wörter?

Comment: "Ansicht" ist übrigens das meistverwendete Wort, "Anschauung" hingegen das am wenigsten übliche Wort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Du hast recht, die drei Wörter sind einander verdammt ähnlich. Deswegen ist es auch nicht leicht, sie voneinander abzugrenzen.

Eine **Auffassung** ist eher etwas, das man schnell aufge*griffen* hat; es ist nicht wirklich tief verankert, es könnte auch nur eine Interimsmeinung sein, bevor man sich ihrer vergewissert hat. Daher auch die *Auffassungsgabe*, die beschreibt, wie schnell man gehörte Sachverhalte einordnen und wiedergeben kann. Es wird meines Erachtens eher verbal als *auffassen* benützt.

> Ich hab das so *aufgefasst*, als wolltest du, dass ich dir den Ring kaufe.
>   Nach meiner *Auffassung* – aber ich bin erst zwei Wochen hier – gibt es für fünf Minuten Verspätung noch keinen Ärger.

Die **Ansicht** – dort, wo sie nicht im Sinne wie *Blickwinkel* gebraucht wird – fußt schon etwas mehr auf tiefergehender Erfahrung. Man muss quasi etwas eine Zeit lang beobachtet – *angesehen* – haben, bevor man eine Ansicht darüber haben kann. Man hat sie zwar noch nicht in kontrollierten Experimenten überprüft wie eine Theorie, aber es deutet doch schon viel darauf hin, dass sie dem experimentellen Test standhalten wird.

> Nach meiner Ansicht explodieren Autos im Straßenverkehr nicht.
>   Mit meinen vielen Lebensjahren Erfahrung bin ich der Ansicht, dass du völlig danebenliegst.

Sie kann aber auch schon in die Richtung einer *Anschauung* gehen:

> Die rechtslastigen Ansichten des Täters brachten ihn dazu, eine Bombe in der Stadt auszulegen.

Die **Anschauung** ist wiederum etwas noch Festgefahreneres; vergleiche auch die *Weltanschauung*. Es ist schwer, eine Anschauung auf ihren Wahrheitsgehalt zu überprüfen; sie wird meines Erachtens eher dort angewendet, wo es um unverifizierbare Meinungen geht. Oft geht es aber auch nur um eben eine festgefahrene Weltanschauung oder Weltsicht.

> In der Anschauung liberaler Parteien sind Steuern Teufelszeug und der Staat muss möglichst klein gehalten werden.
>   Seine Anschauung ist, dass alle Preußen militaristisch sind.

Weder *Ansicht* noch *Anschauung* können in diesen Kontexten durch die jeweiligen Verben *ansehen* oder *anschauen* ersetzt werden, da die Verben etwas anderes bedeuten.

Einen Menschen von seiner *Auffassung* abzubringen kann leicht sein. Eine *Ansicht* zu ändern ist schon sehr schwer, und jemandes *Anschauung* durch Argumentation zu drehen, schier unmöglich.

Über anderslautende Ansichten in Kommentaren oder weiteren Antworten freue ich mich. Gegebenenfalls lässt sich ja meine Auffassung ändern.

Comment: Im großen und ganzen stimme ich den Ansichten von Jan zu, mit einer kleinen Abweichung.
Du schreibst, als ob jede Anschauung / Weltanschauung automatisch etwas festgefahrenes, verhärtetes sein müßte. Bzw. ich verstehe / interpretiere es so. Was ist wenn meine Anschauung bzw Weltanschauung ist, sich zu bemühen, stets offen und freundlich allen gegenüber zu sein und stets davon auszugehen, das, wenn man keine weitere Information hat, der andere gutwillig ist, selbst wenn die Situation es anders erscheinen lassen könnte. In so einem Falle es einfach sein lassen, wenn der andere aggressiv oder ver

Comment: @Rava: Dein Kommentar ist geschnitten worden. Vielleicht sollst du es in neuem Kommentar ergänzen?

Comment: Dazu ein Einstein Zitat: *"Der Horizont der meisten Menschen ist ein Kreis mit dem Radius Null. Und das nennen sie dann ihren Standpunkt."*