# What’s the difference between “Ansicht” and “Meinung”?

Tags: difference, meaning

It seems that both *Ansicht* and *Meinung* mean *opinion.* So what’s their difference?

Comment: Related: [Unterschied zwischen „Ansicht“, „Anschauung“ und „Auffassung“](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/23084/9551)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's  the same difference *as point of view* (Ansicht) and *opinion* (Meinung).

eg. *Meiner Ansicht nach* translates to *in my (point of) view* but *Meiner Meinung nach* translates to *in my opinion*. But both is often used interchangeably both in English and in German.

Let me quote from a [blog article](http://whowritesforyou.com/2011/01/06/perspective-opinion-and-point-of-view-%E2%80%94-distinctions-that-matter-to-writers-and-readers/) I found about this:

> What you see or think at any moment comes from a point of view. How
>   you understand it in relationship to other objects or ideas is your
>   perspective. What you state about it beyond simple fact is your
>   opinion.

I wouldn't be able to describe it any better and the more I think about it, the more it seems philosophical.

Answer (score 2):

[Jaschas answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/24812/8775) is correct but misses the fact that *Ansicht* may also mean a *view* in general, i.e. if it is not used as in *point of view*. An example would be *Ansichtskarte*, a postcard with the view of a panorama on it.